# Pedestal Doesn't serve static resource

Tags: javascript, clojure, pedestal, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I am trying to build on the Pedestal tutorial app available [here](http://pedestal.io/guides/hello-world-content-types).

I am trying to add cljs functionality and trying to setup a unified clojurescript and clojure environment.

My deps.edn file looks as follows:

```
{:paths ["src"]
 :deps {io.pedestal/pedestal.service {:mvn/version "0.5.7"}
    io.pedestal/pedestal.route   {:mvn/version "0.5.7"}
    io.pedestal/pedestal.jetty   {:mvn/version "0.5.7"}
    org.slf4j/slf4j-simple       {:mvn/version "1.7.28"}
    org.clojure/core.async       {:mvn/version "1.3.610"}
    org.clojure/tools.namespace  {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}
    org.clojure/tools.logging    {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}
    org.clojure/data.json        {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}
    org.clojure/clojurescript    {:mvn/version "1.10.758"}
    thheller/shadow-cljs         {:mvn/version "2.11.23"}
    selmer/selmer                {:mvn/version "1.12.33"}
    hiccup/hiccup                {:mvn/version "1.0.5"}}
 :mvn/repos {"central"  {:url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/"}
         "clojars"  {:url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}}}
```

My Shadow-cljs.edn file is as follows

```
{:source-paths ["src/cljs"]
 :nrepl {:port 9000}
 :dependencies [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.21.0"]]
 :builds {:app {:target :browser
            :output-dir "resources/public/js"
            :modules {:main {:init-fn frontend.core/init-fn}}}}}
```

My Folder structure looks as follows:

[image]

The website doesn't do anything different from the pedestal tutorial, aside from using selmer to render an HTML template to create a H1 tag with "Hello, World!" or "Hello, name!". Inside the html I've included the main.js generated from clojurescript by shadow-cljs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, {{name}}</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My core.clj has the following route definition

```
(def routes
(route/expand-routes
  #{["/hello" :get [coerce-body content-neg-intc respond-hello] :route-name :greet]
    ["/echo" :get echo]}))

(defn create-server
     []
   (http/create-server
       {::http/routes routes
        ::http/type   :jetty
        ::http/port   8800
        ::http/join?  false
        ::http/resource-path  ["resources/public" "resources/public/js" "resources/public/js/cljs-runtime"]
        ::http/secure-headers {:content-security-policy-settings {:object-src "none"}}}))
```

As you can see I have added the resources folder in the resource-path.

I am able to run the shadow-cljs and clj in parallel terminals and host the server as follows:
[image]

When I look at chrome for the hosted page I get the following.
[image]

No matter what I do I can't add the public folder in resources to the html path on the client. Such that I can not load the main.js with the page. Why is that? I am a newbie with both clojure and pedestal so maybe I am missing something obvious. Please can someone help me with this problem? I am not sure how to proceed. The Pedestal documentation is not very detailed in this regard.

- Abe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your setup:

1. The key `::http/resource-path` takes a single element and not a vector.
2. As the name of the key indicates, the path must be a resource in the Java sense: the files are actually loaded by a ClassLoader (the resource could be inside a jar file).

In your case, you can do the following:

1. add `"resources"` to the `:src` in your deps.edn file (the maven repo config is not necessary as maven central and clojars are always included);
2. use `"public"` as value for the key `::http/resource-path`.

Your edn file becomes:

```
{:paths ["src" "resources"]
 :deps {io.pedestal/pedestal.service {:mvn/version "0.5.7"}
    io.pedestal/pedestal.route   {:mvn/version "0.5.7"}
    io.pedestal/pedestal.jetty   {:mvn/version "0.5.7"}
    org.slf4j/slf4j-simple       {:mvn/version "1.7.28"}
    org.clojure/core.async       {:mvn/version "1.3.610"}
    org.clojure/tools.namespace  {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}
    org.clojure/tools.logging    {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}
    org.clojure/data.json        {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}
    org.clojure/clojurescript    {:mvn/version "1.10.758"}
    thheller/shadow-cljs         {:mvn/version "2.11.23"}
    selmer/selmer                {:mvn/version "1.12.33"}
    hiccup/hiccup                {:mvn/version "1.0.5"}}}
```

Your server config becomes:

```
(defn create-server
     []
   (http/create-server
       {::http/routes routes
        ::http/type   :jetty
        ::http/port   8800
        ::http/join?  false
        ::http/resource-path  "public"
        ::http/secure-headers {:content-security-policy-settings {:object-src "none"}}}))
```

Comment: Stanislas man!! you are a genius!! This worked for me!! YAY!!! Thank you soo much!!

Answer (score 0):

See http://pedestal.io/cookbook/index#_how_to_serve_static_resources. Note in particular that Pedestal's http/resource-path holds not a file-system location, but rather a URL path prefix by which Pedestal should recognize things it should redeem  from the classpath.

Comment: I looked at this page. It told me to add the :resource-path key in the create-server map. I have this already in my code. Am I doing something wrong? I've tried all combination of paths e.g. /resource /resouce/js /js etc. Nothing works. Do you know given my folder structure what should be used? Sorry to bother you with yet more questions.

Comment: Have you ever try to use just `::http/resource-path  "resources/public"` because this key expects a string value, not a vector.

http://pedestal.io/reference/service-map

Comment: As I explained above, I tried all the generic paths as single strings already. The vector was my last ditch attempt to add all together. I have selected Stanislas's answer as the correct one. This actually works for me. I wish the Pedestal documentation will explain this in more detail.... I really like Pedestal and would like to build more using it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should double check your deps.edn and make sure it includes

```
:paths ["src" "resources"]
```

I had the same problem as you until I found out that I wrote "paths" wrong as "path" which would cause the server can't locate the static resource path.
Good luck!